# How to customize height of header field in Grid?

Tags: angular

I have one of some  `grid-tile`:

```
 <md-grid-tile class="header">
    <md-card class="content">
      <md-card-header>
        <md-card-title>Monday</md-card-title>
        <md-card-subtitle>29.03.17</md-card-subtitle>
      </md-card-header>
    </md-card>
  </md-grid-tile>
```

How to set custom height for this block `<md-grid-tile class="header">`?

I tried to make grid table with headers as `<th>`.

Comment: You are referring to Angular (2+), not AngularJS (1.x) correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<md-grid-tile>   
    <md-grid-tile-header>
        <h3>This is a header</h3> <-- Places classes here.
    </md-grid-tile-header> 
</md-grid-tile>
```

[Documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdGridTile)

Comment: May be I am wrong, I try to do header from grid-cell. Possible it should be div element in grid-cell, right?

Comment: But another problem that grid has own height, therefore div inside grid field has the same parent height, that is not suitable for me

Comment: This documentation is compatible with Angular 1, not for 4

Answer (score 1):

You will want to create a row height, then have each tile be a certain number of rows. If you set each row to 5, and set your first tile to be the max number of columns and 5 rows then you will have a full length tile 25 pixels tall. Here's a [plunker for an example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fv09nUfNdlcdWWXjd8wl?p=preview) and the general form of the code:

```
<md-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="5">
  <md-grid-tile rowspan="5" colspan="4">Title</md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile rowspan="10" colspan="2">Tile 1</md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile rowspan="15" colspan="2">Tile 2</md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile rowspan="20" colspan="4">Tile 3</md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

Comment: I need to have 7 columns with 7 headers. Also can I set height in percentage?

Comment: I updated the plunker for 7 columns, 7 headers. You must use pixels with grid-list/grid-tile.

Comment: I can not use percents? Header should be 1/2 of others fields(body fields)

Comment: You can't use percents, but if you set the rowspan for the title to half the other tiles rowspan you will acheive 1/2 height. I updated the plunker to show this.

Comment: You mean this: rowspan="10" rowspan="20".?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean!

Comment: Excellent answer! Please follow me, I ask the intresting question about new Angular Material 4, because there are not a lot information about this in network.